# How to downgrade Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (21.04) to Focal Fossa (20.04) LTS?

Tags: 20.04, downgrade, 21.04

How to downgrade Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (21.04) to Focal Fossa (20.04) LTS?

Or that's not actually an option?

Comment: That's not an option, you'll have do perform a fresh installation of 20.04.

Comment: You'll know what backup strategy you have in place, so only you can really know..  Be aware that some programs store data in a way that earlier versions of the same program have trouble with (ie. I didn't like 11.10 long ago, so rolled back to 11.04 to find many of my emails received whilst using the newer version were invisible after rollback in my chosen MUA.  The mail wasn't removed; it became visible once I upgraded to later versions of the program again.... ie. you need to check yourself for the programs that matter to you as QA-testing is always to the later release, not the other way)